# How to encode and decode JSON to TypeScript Model with abstract inheritance?

Tags: json, typescript

I have a TypeScript data model, where one class contains a list with an **abstract** data type. I want **encode** this model to JSON and **decode** it from JSON.

Let's assume this following simplified model:

```
class Vendor {
    vehicles: Vehicle[];
}

abstract class Vehicle {
    wheels: number;
}

class Bike extends Vehicle { }

class Car extends Vehicle {
    doors: number;
}
```

The problem: At runtime we do not know about the data type of each element in the vehicle list.

---

What I've tried so far:

I add the data type as a `className` field to the JSON string:

```
class Vendor {
    vehicles: Vehicle[];
}


interface VehicleJSON {
    className: string;
    wheels: number;
}
abstract class Vehicle {
    wheels: number;

    toJSON(): VehicleJSON {
        return Object.assign({ className: this.constructor.name }, this);
    }
}


class Bike extends Vehicle { }


interface CarJSON extends VehicleJSON {
    doors: number;
}
class Car extends Vehicle {
    doors: number;

    toJSON(): CarJSON {
        return Object.assign({ className: this.constructor.name }, this);
    }
}
```

This adds a `className` field to every bike and every car object. Encoding seems to work as intendet.

Now to the decoding part. Unfortunately, I did not come up with a good solution. This looks a little bit clunky:

```
[...]

interface VehicleJSON {
    className: string;
    wheels: number;
}
abstract class Vehicle {
    public static fromJSON(json: any): Vehicle {
        switch (json.className) {
            case Bike.constructor.name:
                return Bike.fromJson(json as VehicleJSON);

            case Car.constructor.name:
                return Car.fromJSON(json as CarJSON);

            default: 
            throw new Error();
        }
    }
    [...]
}


class Bike extends Vehicle {
    public static fromJSON(json: VehicleJSON): Bike {
        const vehicle = Object.create(Bike.prototype);
        return Object.assign(vehicle, json);
    }
}


interface CarJSON extends VehicleJSON {
    doors: number;
}
class Car extends Vehicle {
    public static fromJSON(json: CarJSON): Car {
        const vehicle = Object.create(Car.prototype);
        return Object.assign(vehicle, json);
    }
    [...]
}
```

The code above compiles, but does not run, because of circular Dependencies. The parent class `Vehicle` uses static functions from it's child classes and the child classes of corse extend from their parent class.

I receive the following error message:

```
class Bike extends vehicle_1.Vehicle

TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
```

I hope you can help me with my problem and come up with a better solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the parsing counterpart to the stringification replacer function, the parsing *reviver* function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter

A reviver function allows you to examine the key/value pairs provided by JSON, and return your own values -- which can include your own custom classes.

Also, if you don't mind me touting my own little project, I've made my own JSON stringifier/parser that specializes in handling custom data types: https://json-z.org/

One of the options above will encode custom objects in such a way that you can still use standard JSON, along with an appropriate reviver function, to parse the data.